# How to write links to a text file?

Tags: python

I'm testing the following script:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import fileinput

Link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1990'
q = requests.get(Link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
#print soup
subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'links'})
#print subtitles


with  open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:
    for link in subtitles:
        x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)
        for a in x:
            url = a['href']
            f.write(url+'\n')
```

I'm trying to get each link copied/pasted to a text file.  The script seems like it should work, but it doesn't actually do anything.

How can I get this working?

Comment: You only want to have a list of strings seperated by newlines in the file?

Comment: Or do you want to write the content of the link url in a file?

Comment: Shouldn't you be fetching soup.findAll('a',{'class':'CategoryTreeLabel'}) if you want all links to the category?

Comment: I tried this; it didn't do anything.
soup.findAll('a',{'class':'CategoryTreeLabel'})

@pal sch, how can I do both things?
#1)  List of strings separated by returns
#2)  Write the contents of the URL to a text file

I'm just starting to learn this stuff, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at your script step by step and figure out which part isn't doing what you expect. You are using two queries in BS4 that may return empty if no match is found. Are you getting an empty file full of linebreaks? Are you even getting a file?

Comment: Or maybe you want to get all links in a website? Then my solution would be wrong for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a string to a text file like this:

`with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
   f.write(yourstr)`

If you don't want to override the file just use "a" as second parameter in open. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open.

So, I assume that you have a list of links like this:

> ["http://example.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]

and you want to have a file like this:

```
http://example.com:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
...
<h1>Example Domain</h1>
...
</body>
</html>

http://stackoverflow.com:
...
```

Let's start with iterating all the links:

```
for url in yourlinks:
```

First, you want to write the url to the file:

```
    with open("yourfile.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(url+"\n") # the \n is a new line
```

Now you download the content of the website to a variable:

```
        content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

(It may be that there are errors because of encoding - I'm from python3.)
And you write it to the file:

```
        f.write(content+"\n")
```

Voila! You should have your file now.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting an error that reads 'unidentified name urllib2'.  Here's my sample code, which I know is wrong, but probably close.

Comment: import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import fileinput

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1990'
q = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
#print soup
subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'links'})
#print subtitles


with  open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:
    for link in subtitles:
        x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)
        for a in x:
            url = a['href']
            f.write(url+'\n')
            
    for links in url:
        with open("Anilinks.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(links+"\n") # the \n is a new line

Comment: Oh great, now I can't format the code so you can actually read it.  Argh!!

Comment: @ryguy7272 You have to import urllib2.

Comment: And, in my opinion, you don't need any requests - I do the download with urllib2.

Comment: Ok, what does the whole script look like?  I think this is close, but it's still not doing anything, other than adding a newline after each character of the original URL.

Comment: import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import fileinput
import urllib2

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1990'
q = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
#print soup
subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'links'})
#print subtitles


with  open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:
    for link in subtitles:
        x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)
        for a in x:
            url = a['href']
            f.write(url+'\n')
            
    for links in url:
        with open("Anilinks.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(links+"\n")

Comment: HOW DO YOU ADD FORMATTED CODE?  ABOUT 10% OF THE TIME CTRL+K WORKS AND THE REST OF THE TIME IT DOES NOTHING.

Comment: @ryguy7272 the whole code is the import stuff, then variables init and then every code line after "Let's start" in my answer.

Comment: Can you please send me an email?  
ryanshuell at gmail dot com
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are no divs with a class of links on that page so `for link in subtitles` does not have any items to iterate.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> Link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1990'
>>> q = requests.get(Link)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
>>> subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'links'})
>>> subtitles
[]
```

You are opening your output file in write mode before trying to loop results so you are always getting an empty file.