# How to save attachments from websites using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, get, python-requests

I've written a code to scrape attachments attached in a website. It essentially scrapes the hyperlinks to the attachments. I'm not able to figure out a way to save the directly save those attachment in local location.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/amfi-monthly'
response = get(url,verify=False)
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

filetype = '.xls'
excel_sheets = html_soup.find_all('a')

#File name where the links to the excel sheet needs to be saved --> here: "All_Links_2.csv"
destination = open('All_Links_2.csv','wb')

for link in excel_sheets:
    href = link.get('href') + '\n'
    if filetype in href:
        print(href)
```

Can anyone help here??

Comment: `destination.write(href)` instead of `print(href)`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289247/how-to-write-links-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really something you do with beautiful soup, instead we use the urllib library.

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve(href, "file.jpg")
```

This takes the image address and saves it as `file.jpg`. If you want different filenames, which applies in your case make the string `"file" + i + ".jpg"`, with `i` being some value you increment

Comment: Thanks Shrey. But urllib seems to be not recognize the url of the attachment.
Code:


`
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

filetype = '.xls'
excel_sheets = html_soup.find_all('a')

for link in excel_sheets:
    href = link.get('href') + '\n'
    if filetype in href:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(href,"file.xls")
`

Error : <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

You can visit this website : https://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/amfi-monthly
I'm trying to download the attachments here

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to only get the links then there's no need for binary mode, also since you have **pandas** imported you can use that to save them.

First create a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([a['href'] for a in excel_sheets if filetype in a['href']])
```

Then just save it without column names (header=False):

```py
df.to_csv('All_Links_2.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Bagon for the inputs.
However, I'm trying to download the attachment from the websites. I tried saving the links in a csv and then retrieving them, however the hyperlink format doesn't stick while extracting again from CSV. 
It'll be helpful if you could help me retain the hyperlink format while extracting the links from csv.